# Equality of ideals for every value of one variable implies they are equal?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, polynomial-rings

Let $J\subseteq I$ be ideals in a polynomial ring $R=\mathbb{F}[x_1, \ldots, x_n, t]$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ of characteristic zero. Let's write $I_{\lambda}$ for the ideal in $S=\mathbb{F}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ obtained by setting $t=\lambda\in \mathbb{F}$ in the ideal $I$ and similarly for $J_{\lambda}$. Suppose
$$I_{\lambda}=J_{\lambda} \; \mathrm{ in }\; S \; \mathrm{ for every } \; \lambda \in \mathbb{F}.$$
Does that imply $I=J$ in $R$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Just take $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Q}$, $n=0$ and $I=(t),\ J=(t^2)$. Of course, this generalizes to higher values of $n$ trivially.

I think that the radicals of $I$ and $J$ should coincide, though.

Comment: The radicals of $I$ and $J$ need not coincide if we are working over $\mathbb{Q}$. In the case $n = 0$, writing $I = (f)$ and $J = (g)$, we see that $f(\lambda)$ and $g(\lambda)$ generate the same ideal in $\mathbb{Q}$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $f$ and $g$ have the same zeroes. So $I = (t)$, $J = (t(t^2-2))$ is another example over $\mathbb{Q}$. However, it is true that the radicals would have to coincide if we were working over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Thank for taking the time to reply to my question! Is there also a simple counter-example if we additionally assume $I$ can be generated by polynomials that do not depend on $t$?

Comment: @Simon Not over the rationals, just compare $I$ and $J=(t^2+1)\cdot I$.

Comment: @IDC right, it's obvious now you said it! I probably should have stated the exact problem I have instead of trying to generalize it. If you don't mind me asking yet another question. The precise situation I have is as follows: I have an ideal $I$ generated by polynomials that do not depend on $t$ and an ideal $J$ that is a subset of $I$ and generated by polynomials linear in $t$. I can prove $J_{\lambda}=I$ (considered as ideals of $S$) for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ and I want to conclude they are equal in $R$. I don't suppose that is true, is it?

Comment: @Simon It would be better for you to ask that as a new question. I will think about it when I have the time.